# Authentication with Microsoft for existing users

Tags: asp.net, authentication, oauth-2.0, openid, claims-based-identity

I'm developing a Webapp with (ext)ASP.NET that already has users registered. I'm trying to add Authentication with Microsoft (OpenID Connect).

My problem is, that I don't know how I should connect the existing users to their respective Microsoft account. After the first time they have logged in, I should have the "sub" saved in my database, and can compare users with that.

But the first time, I don't know what to do. I can't really check for email in they payload in "preferred_username", since that is mutable.

My second question is, is saving the "sub" in my Database the wrong approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question and it is a common requirement to identify users in your app after login. Especially if users have a history with your app, such as orders placed, and you want to maintain this while migrating logins to Azure AD (or wherever).

My preference is the following approach:

- Ensure that the Authorization Server contains emails for existing users
- I would recommend storing a copy of the sub claim in the app database
- After login, try to find a match in your app on the sub claim
- If not found then try to match on the email claim

My blog post on [User Data Management](https://authguidance.com/2017/10/02/user-data/) may give you further ideas on patterns to follow. If your problem is a Microsoft specific technical issue with getting the email claim, please post back with further details - I may be able to help you with that.